# How to encrypt a single element if a JSON response in Mule?

Tags: encryption, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have a JSON message say

```
{"menu": {
"id": "file",
"value": "File",
"popup": {
"menuitem": [
  {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
  {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
  {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
]
 }
}}
```

I would want to encrypt on the Id field in the JSON like below.

```
{"menu": {
"id": "98jshr0837@",
"value": "File",
"popup": {
"menuitem": [
 {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
 {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
] 
 }
}}
```

I use the below code for encryption:

```
 <flow name="hf-eai-crm-plan-search-detail-api-flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payload.menu.id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      <encryption:decrypt config-ref="Encryption" doc:name="Encryption"/>  
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

Let me know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your flow a bit and able to get **encrypted** value of a **single** element as follows :-

```
<flow name="hf-eai-crm-plan-search-detail-api-flow" doc:name="hf-eai-crm-plan-search-detail-api-flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <logger message="before encryption #[message.payload.menu.id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <encryption:encrypt config-ref="Encryption" doc:name="Encryption" using="JCE_ENCRYPTER" input-ref="#[message.payload.menu.id]"/>
    <logger message="After encryption #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <encryption:decrypt config-ref="Encryption" using="JCE_ENCRYPTER" doc:name="Decrypt the xml payload" />
    <logger message="Element After Decryption :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" category="NormalEncryption" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

You can see in the below screenshots for your reference :-
[image]

I have **also** **decrypted** to show you the value of element

**EDITED Solution**
Well, there is an attribute xpath in `<encryption/>` which can be used to encrypt an element in XML. But unfortunately, I didn't find anything for JSON that can parse it and encrypt an element from it... So I created the following 2 solutions for you :-

**Solution1**:-

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<encryption:config name="Encryption" enableLanguage="true" doc:name="Encryption">
<encryption:jce-encrypter-config algorithm="CAST5" key="poso123456789lal" />
</encryption:config>
<flow name="hf-eai-crm-plan-search-detail-api-flow" >
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[message.payload.menu.value]" variableName="value"/>
    <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[message.payload.menu.popup]" variableName="popup"/>
    <logger message="before encryption #[message.payload.menu.id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <encryption:encrypt config-ref="Encryption" doc:name="Encryption" using="JCE_ENCRYPTER" input-ref="#[message.payload.menu.id]"/>
    <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[message.payload]" variableName="id"/>
    <logger message="Encryption #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

     <expression-transformer
     expression="#[[ 
                    'menu':[
                    'id': flowVars.id,
                    'value': flowVars.value,
                    'popup': flowVars.popup
                    ]

                   ]
      ]" doc:name="Expression"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>  

     <logger message="After encryption  #['\n' + message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

Here you can see I have parsed the JSON payload and saved each element value in variables, and then using the variables I am able to construct the JSON you required **dynamically** using **Expression Transformer** and also included the **encrypted** element in it.

**Alternate Solution** :-

```
<flow name="hf-eai-crm-plan-search-detail-api-flow" >
   <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>

      <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[message.payload]" variableName="myPayload"/>
      <logger message="before encryption #[message.payload.menu.id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[message.payload]" variableName="id"/>
      <encryption:encrypt config-ref="Encryption" doc:name="Encryption" using="JCE_ENCRYPTER" input-ref="#[message.payload.menu.id]"/>
      <logger message="Encryption #[message.payload] " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      <expression-transformer expression="#[flowVars.myPayload.menu.id=message.payload;flowVars.myPayload]" />
      <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>   

     <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/> 
</flow>​
```

Here you can see, using **Expression transformer**, I am able to **update** only the element I required to **encrypt**

So using any of the above solution you will get to **encrypt** the element you require in the JSON as below :-

[image]

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thank you @Anirban . But I have achieved this part and I will need the whole JSON as the payload instead of the single field. The json should have the ID field which is encrypted. Edited my question to get desired output

Comment: Can we not make the transformation to map or hash map and achieve this. I have a similar solution but would like to avoid the overhead of the json transformer

Answer (score 0):

To keep the payload we can utilize Message Enricher. Please refer to the following configuration, it might meet your purpose:

```
<flow name="hf-eai-crm-plan-search-detail-api-flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/encrypt" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="POST" />
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
    <logger message="The JSON before encryption: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - initial" />
    <enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[payload.menu.id]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <encryption:encrypt config-ref="Encryption" input-ref="#[message.payload.menu.id]" using="JCE_ENCRYPTER" doc:name="Encryption"/>
    </enricher>
    <logger message="The JSON after encryption: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - id encrypted" />
    <enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[payload.menu.id]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <encryption:decrypt config-ref="Encryption" input-ref="#[payload.menu.id]" using="JCE_ENCRYPTER" doc:name="Decryption"/>
    </enricher>
    <logger message="The JSON after decryption: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - decrypted (back to original)" />
</flow>
```

The result of this configuration is:
[image]

Comment: Hi Sulthony. I have a similar solution by my self but need to know if we can do it without the Json to object transformer .

Comment: Without transforming JSON to object, I think we should work on String manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Without JSON to Object transformer, just modifying your configuration and add a little bit tricky String manipulation:

```
<flow name="hf-eai-crm-plan-search-detail-api-flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/encrypt" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="POST" />
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <logger message="The JSON before encryption: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - initial" />
    <set-variable variableName="jsonOriginal" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Keep the original JSON"/>
    <set-payload value="#[json:menu]" doc:name="Set Payload with JSON menu"/>
    <set-variable variableName="idValue" value="#[json:id]" doc:name="Get value of id"/>
    <encryption:encrypt config-ref="Encryption" input-ref="#[flowVars.idValue]" using="JCE_ENCRYPTER" doc:name="Encryption"/>
    <logger message="The id after encryption: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - id encrypted" />
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars.jsonOriginal.replaceAll(&quot;\&quot;id\&quot;: \&quot;&quot; + flowVars.idValue + &quot;\&quot;&quot;, &quot;\&quot;id\&quot;: \&quot;&quot; + payload + &quot;\&quot;&quot;)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message="The JSON after encryption: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Final JSON" />
</flow>
```

Following is the result:
[image]